# how to show chart after clicking on button in flex?

Tags: xml, apache-flex

I have made menu bar.  I have taken 4 options on it.
Now when i click on one option from menu bar then i want to show chart.  How to achieve it?

Thanks in Advance--

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't share code, here is how you do it conceptually:

1. Listen for the click event on the
   menu bar option.
2. Toggle visibility of the chart in the click handler.  This can be done by toggling the visible property from true to false; or by changing a state.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to add an event listener to that menu bar to know when you've selected the 'option' that's suppose to show a chart.  When that handler is triggered, add that view to your display list (the one with the chart).